# Strange output query Elastic Search

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch

I just started with using Elastic Search. I've got everything set-up correctly. I'm using Firebase + [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) + Elastic Search.

In my front-end I'm building queries based on different search params.  I insert them into a node in Firebase `/search/requests/`. Flashlight will pick this up and putting the response into `/search/response`, this works like a charm!

However, I'm not sure how to write my queries properly. I'm getting strange results when I'm trying to combine two `must` `match` queries. I'm using Query DSL.

My documents in Elastic Search under `deliverables/doc` are having the following scheme.

```
...
{
  "createdBy" : "admin@xx.org",
  "createdOn" : 1501200000000,
  "deadLine" : 1508716800000,
  "description" : {
    "value" : "dummy description"
  },
  "key" : "<FBKEY>",

  "programmes" : [ {
    "code" : "95000",
    "name" : "Test programme",
    "programYear" : 2017
  } ],
  "projects" : [ {
    "projectCode" : "113200",
    "projectName" : "Test project",
    "projectYear" : 2017
  } ],
  "reportingYear" : 2017,
  "status" : "Open",
  "type" : "writing",
  "updatedBy" : "admin@xx.org",
  "updatedOn" : 1501200000000,
},
...
```

My query has the following structure.

```
{
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "createdBy": "xx@company.org"
          },
          "match": {
            "programmes.code": "95000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In my output I'm also getting documents that don't have exactly those two fields? They have a very low score as well. Is this normal?

My mapping, automatically created using Flashlight

[image]

**Update 1**

I just tried this query, however it still gives me strange results by not filtering on both fields:

```
   {
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "programmes.code": "890000"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "createdBy": "admin@xx.org"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `must` clause used in `bool query` is executed in **query context**(all the documents are returned in decreasing order of score) and contributes to score. [see link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query)

If you want it to be executed as a filter, then use the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "createdBy": "xx@company.org"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "programmes.code": "95000"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

By default the string field is analyzed, update the mapping of the string fields as `not_analyzed`, to use `filter` query. Refer: [mapping-intro](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2)

Comment: I just tried this query, however it still gives me strange results by not filtering on both fields. See update in start post

Comment: One modification is you could do is replace `match` with `term` so that it does not analyze the field.

Comment: If I replace `match` with `term` I get zero results? If I filter on `programmes.code` it works. But somehow the combination with `programmes.code` and `createdBy` (same as for other combinations) doesn't work.

Comment: The combination does not work implies, that there are no documents which satisfy both the conditions. Note that it `must` does boolean `AND`, may be you're looking for is a `should` clause which will return if any one of the conditions are met.

Comment: I do have a document with both the exact fields but somehow it only filters on the program and not on the createdBy

Comment: could you update the document and also it's corresponding mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154148/discussion-between-chandra-praneeth-n-and-rover).

Comment: I've just updated the mapping and an example document

Comment: I've queried my database for both `createdBy` and `programme.code`. I'm getting back 81 records, 13 correct, 68 records matching only `programme.code`

Comment: The problem lies with the mapping. By default the string field is analyzed. Hence you're getting strange results. If you update the mapping of those fields as `not_analyzed', you can use filter query to get correct results.
check this for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2